# Removing multiple lines between brackets

Tags: server, sed, client

I have the following

```
 "endPoints" : [

 "127.0.0.1:8090/abskdj/index.html",
   "127.0.0.1:8091/qwe/we.html"
    ],
```

(may contain one or more addresses)

I want to change that to

```
"endPoints" : [
           ],
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is suitable for deleting contents between two patterns.

```
$ sed -i '/"endPoints" : \[/,/\]/{//!d}' file
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46434705/12007102) is a good summary of some common uses.

Comment: Thank you.  How can i replace these addresses from a file add.txt in/root/home. I had tried but failed

$ sed -e '/"endPoints" : \[/,/\]/{/r /root/home/add.txt/!d}'

Comment: you want in-place replacement.

Comment: Yes i want replacement by removing old Values and take new values from /root/home/add.txt

Comment: think you are asking for something like: `jq < file.json --slurpfile entries add.txt '.endPoints = $entries'` you need to update your question so that it reflects what you want

Comment: If you need to quote your entries you can use sed `--slurpfile entries <(sed 's/.*/"&"/' add.txt)`